# Minimal permissions for Kubernetes backup with Kasten on AWS S3

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to set up a Location profile for Kasten to perform backup on a S3 bucket on AWS. The documentation recommends giving minimal permissions to the user/role designated to perform the backup, but I keep getting an error when trying to add the profile only with those permissions in my IAM policy.
https://docs.kasten.io/latest/usage/configuration.html#profile-creation

When I give full S3 access to the user, the profile is added correctly, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct minimal permissions are a combination of the permissions specified on these 2 pages in the documentation:

1. https://docs.kasten.io/latest/usage/configuration.html#profile-creation
2. https://docs.kasten.io/latest/install/aws/using_aws_iam_roles.html#using-aws-iam-roles

Here is how your minimal permissions policy should look like (just replace your bucket name at the end):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectRetention",
            "s3:PutObjectRetention",
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET_NAME}/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```